# How would I fix these distorted normal map bake pixels?

Tags: objects, texture-baking

I've been using a cage to make normals map info from a High Poly Object to a Low Poly. When previewed inside Blender it appears fine, however, any time I export the baked texture to a game engine what was originally straight becomes crooked. How could I fix this?

[image: As seen in Blender]

[image: As seen inside Roblox Studio]

Comment: Probably, differently triangulated meshes.  Don't export quad meshes; engines can triangulate them differently, leading to differences in UV (and normal, and vertex color) interpolation across the face.  If you have no concave quads, consider using a triangulate modifier on "fixed" with "keep normals" to triangulate the mesh in the way that Blender triangulates it.  If you have concave quads-- well, you should fix the concave quads, but to my knowledge, there's currently no quick fix.  Maybe triangulate concave quads manually and data transfer normals from an original.

Comment: I could see how this might help however the actual image has these crooked lines as well.
https://prnt.sc/3PiOVmm0WOWT

Comment: That's expected.  The triangulation is baked into the actual image on a high-to-low bake.

Comment: Would rebaking this with triangulation fix this?

Comment: Rebaking it with the triangulation your ultimate exporter/engine expects *might* fix it-- right now, it's just a suspicion.  Even so, you don't know what triangulation that is.  So tell it how you want it triangulated, by triangulating it yourself, rebaking, and then exporting, and see if that fixes the issue.  What I was saying with using "fixed" triangulation to export just frees you the extra bake step, because "fixed" is what Blender uses for convex quads.

Comment: I've tried rebaking it with the traingulation but now the normals are distorted
https://prnt.sc/l9jhWsVOa7cE

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: That is not a good bake; that is probably an object-space bake, as opposed to the tangent-space bake you showed earlier, but it's not impossible that something else is going on.  This really isn't a good site for back and forth; I'd recommend asking someplace like blenderartists.org instead, which is friendlier to comments.

Comment: Thank you for your help.